# What can we do? The site seems to stagnate

Tags: discussion

Looking at the current [Area 51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2578/philosophy)... we need some work: only **3.1 questions per day**, where 15 is a healthy beta.

**What can we do to gain more activity on the site?**

Comment: Having watched the stats for about two years now -- that's actually towards the *high* end of our daily questions average... At any rate, I'd submit we're anything but stagnant today; in fact we're about the most active I've ever seen it.

Comment: That said, there's not really any big secret about how to increase questions-per-day -- ask great questions, create great content, increase returning-viewers, engage more deeply with the community, etc. We've done things like question-of-the-week contests centering around certain thinkers or movements; and I've suggested at various points organizing regular study/discussion groups in chat, that could maybe help ideate and develop new questions.

Comment: See also: http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/127/how-can-we-encourage-asking-questions-and-increase-the-rate-of-new-questions

Comment: stop being so pedantic about suitable questions ?

Comment: @DrSister was there any particular concern or problem you want to explore there? We're definitely going to continue requiring questions be practical/answerable -- note this isn't anyone here being "pedantic"; it's a global SE guideline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I'm less concerned about the number of questions per day, and more concerned about the number of high-quality questions.

The *last* thing we should do is encourage more activity, in my opinion, unless we are certain that the activity we encourage would actually be beneficial to the site.